# SQL search for words beginning with A-L

Tags: sql

Basically is there a simpler way to do this:

```
WHERE name LIKE 'A%' OR name LIKE 'B%' ....
```

Without having to type this all the way from A-L.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In most databases you can do:

```
where left(name, 1) between 'A' and 'L'
```

You might need to use `substr()` or `substring()` instead of `left()`.

Answer (score 1):

WHERE name >= 'A' AND name < 'M'